# How to shuffle every second column with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-addon

I want to randomize D:E, F:G, H:I, J:K if C is 4 with google apps script.

[image]

[image]
At the moment I use this inefficient & time-consuming code:

```
function shuffleAnswers() {
 var arr = [0, 2, 4, 6]; 
 for (var i = 2; i < lastRow()+1; i++)
 {
   var amount = sheet().getRange(i,3).getValue();
   if (amount == 4)
   {
     var source = sheet().getRange(i,4,1,2);
     var column = 4 + arr[(Math.random() * arr.length) | 0];
     var destination = sheet().getRange(i,column,1,2);
     var valuesSource = source.getValues();
     var valuesDestination = destination.getValues();
     source.setValues(valuesDestination);
     destination.setValues(valuesSource);     
   }
 }
 arr = [-2, 0, 2, 4]; 
 for (var i = 2; i < lastRow()+1; i++)
 {
   var amount = sheet().getRange(i,3).getValue();
   if (amount == 4)
   {
     var source = sheet().getRange(i,6,1,2);
     var column = 6 + arr[(Math.random() * arr.length) | 0];
     var destination = sheet().getRange(i,column,1,2);
     var valuesSource = source.getValues();
     var valuesDestination = destination.getValues();
     source.setValues(valuesDestination);
     destination.setValues(valuesSource);     
   }
 }
 arr = [-4, -2, 0, 2]; 
 for (var i = 2; i < lastRow()+1; i++)
 {
   var amount = sheet().getRange(i,3).getValue();
   if (amount == 4)
   {
     var source = sheet().getRange(i,8,1,2);
     var column = 8 + arr[(Math.random() * arr.length) | 0];
     var destination = sheet().getRange(i,column,1,2);
     var valuesSource = source.getValues();
     var valuesDestination = destination.getValues();
     source.setValues(valuesDestination);
     destination.setValues(valuesSource);     
   }
 }

 arr = [-6, -4, -2, 0]; 
 for (var i = 2; i < lastRow()+1; i++)
 {
   var amount = sheet().getRange(i,3).getValue();
   if (amount == 4)
   {
     var source = sheet().getRange(i,10,1,2);
     var column = 10 + arr[(Math.random() * arr.length) | 0];
     var destination = sheet().getRange(i,column,1,2);
     var valuesSource = source.getValues();
     var valuesDestination = destination.getValues();
     source.setValues(valuesDestination);
     destination.setValues(valuesSource);     
   }
 }
}
```

Do you have an idea? Maybe with range.randomize()? Every row with C=4 should be randomized. The columns for multiple rows should not be changed to the same position.

Comment: Randomize horizontally right? Could you show the randomized output?

Comment: @TheMaster If my understanding is correct, when I saw 1st part of OP's script, it seems that the rows of columns "D2:E" are randomized. The columns "D" and "E" in each row are not randomized. I think that OP wants to reflect to "D2:E", "F2:G", "H2:I" and "J2:K". But if my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster And also, it seems that OP wants to randomize when the column "C" is `4`. I noticed about it now. Please be careful this.

Comment: @TheMaster https://imgur.com/FEW5bDt randomized output example. Yes, randomize horizontally.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for the bad explanation. Let me explain it a bit better: Loop through all rows -> check if C column cell value of row is 4 -> randomize cell values of columns Answer 1/Correct 1, Answer 2/Correct 2, Answer 3/Correct 3, Answer 4/Correct 4 with each other. It is about a quiz. each row is one question and you see the answers + which answer is correct. I only want to randomize all answers for each question so that I don't have all the correct answers in the same position.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. Op clarified as well.

Comment: @pabsdenn Thank you for replying. I would like to try to understand about your goal. I apologize that I cannot understand it soon.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I could notice that my understanding was not correct. It seems that the horizontal arrow might be the horizontally randomizing. I apologize for this. I would like to try to see the vision of OP's goal. I think that this is the interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why so slow?

- Use of getValues inside the loop slows down the script considerably.  Batching up operations is important.

#### Script Flow:

- Create a random array of numbers between 1 to 8 like, [[1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8]]   and then use those numbers as indexes  for the new row.
- Get all values from the sheet and rearrange only rows where C=4 and set back all values in one shot.

#### Sample script:

```
/* Create a Random arrray of numbers from 1 to 8 with couples
 * eg:[1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8]*/
const doubleShuffleFix = (n = 4) => {
  const generator = function*() {//TODO: boilerplate- can be avoided 
    let i = 1;
    yield i;
    while (true) {
      if (i < (n - 1) * 2) {
        yield (i += 2);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  };
  const available = [...generator()];

  //Durstenfeld algo
  for (let i = available.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [available[i], available[rand]] = [available[rand], available[i]];
  }
  return available.map(num => [num, ++num]).flat();
};

function shuffleAnswer() {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'),
    rg = s.getRange(2, 3, s.getLastRow() - 1, 9),
    values = rg.getValues();

  rg.setValues(
    values.map(row => {
      if (row[0] === 4) {
        return [4, ...doubleShuffleFix().map(num => row[num])];
      }
      return row;
    })
  );
}
```

#### References:

- [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [Durstenfeld algorithm](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: Note: [Enable v8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) before testing

Comment: @TheMaster my thank you comment has been deleted. dont know why. however i noticed one issue. The strings of the questions with 2 answers True or False will be set to lowercase after using your code. They should stay that way "True" and "False" or "TRUE" and "FALSE". Do you know why?

Comment: @pabs Not sure... probably some type correction.. try `.getDisplayValues();` instead of ``.getValues();``. I'm sure that'll fix the issue.

Comment: @TheMaster yes, you are right! `.getDisplayValues();` solved it. Thank you very much for all your help and references! I learned a lot from it.